# Value of custom Date Picker Component in gridPro is always null

Tags: datepicker, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I want to use a DatePicker as custom component in vaadin gridPro.
Since there are only checkbox, select and text natively supported as EditColumn, I tried it with custom.

```
final DatePicker component = new DatePicker();
this.medicationAdjustmentRules.addEditColumn(value -> (value.getValidUntil() != null ? value.getValidUntil().format(this.formatter) : null))
    .custom(component, (medicationAdjustmentRule, newValue) -> medicationAdjustmentRule.setValidUntil(component.getValue() != null ? component.getValue() : newValue))
    .setHeader("validUntil");
```

Both component.getValue() and newValue are always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not tried what you are doing before and it is hard to get the full picture of what you are doing here. Maybe you could try set a value for the DatePicker upfront just to verify if it is still null?

Answer (score 3):

I seem to be able to get a value out of both the component instance and from the ItemUpdater parameter. Here's a full example:

```java
@Route(value = "gridpro", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class GridProView extends VerticalLayout {

    public static class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private LocalDate birthDate;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate birthDate) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getData() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Zach", "Quinto", LocalDate.of(2000, 5, 2)));
        persons.add(new Person("Paula", "Boulon", LocalDate.of(1982, 11, 24)));
        persons.add(new Person("Foo", "Bar", LocalDate.of(2020, 01, 01)));
        return persons;
    }

    public GridProView() {
        GridPro<Person> gridPro = new GridPro<>();
        gridPro.addColumn(Person::getFirstName).setHeader("First name");
        gridPro.addColumn(Person::getLastName).setHeader("Last name");
        DatePicker component = new DatePicker();
        gridPro.addEditColumn(Person::getBirthDate).custom(component,
                (ItemUpdater<Person, LocalDate>) (person, newValue) -> {
                    System.out.println("Value in component: " + component.getValue());
                    System.out.println("newValue: " + newValue);
                    person.setBirthDate(newValue);
                });
        gridPro.setItems(getData());
        add(gridPro);
    }

}
```

This outputs something like:

```
Value in component: 2000-07-18
newValue: 2000-07-18
Value in component: 1981-11-24
newValue: 1981-11-24
Value in component: 2020-01-08
newValue: 2020-01-08
```